# Expand folium map size on mobile devices

Tags: python, django, folium

I make a web app using Django, Folium. I have a navbar and a Folium map on the web page. It works fine om computers and landscape screen devices, but on portrait screen devices the map has a free space.

My code for map:

```
current_map = folium.Map(location=start_location, zoom_start=6)    
fig = branca.element.Figure(height="100%")
fig.add_child(current_map)
context = {"current_map": current_map._repr_html_()}
return render(request, template_name="index.html", context=context)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ current_map | safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

How do I fill it?

[image]

Comment: How did you solve your problem? faced the same problem

Comment: @J.Meirlen I posted an answer. Maybe there is a better approach, but this workes for me.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I might to use Figure and modify folium package.

```
current_map = folium.Map(location=(48.51, 32.25), zoom_start=6)
map_container = branca.element.Figure(height="100%")
map_container.add_child(current_map)
...
context = {"current_map": map_container.render(), "form": form}
return render(request, template_name="hub/index.html", context=context)
```

I downloaded `folium-0.12.1.post1.tar.gz`, and from `folium/folium.py` removed mentions about old versions of Bootstrap from lists `_default_js` and `_default_css`. But I use Bootstrap in `base.html`.

And in `requirements.txt` I use this local modified distr:

```
./distr/folium-0.12.1.post1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
current_map._repr_html_()
```

That give you representation for jupitier notebook.
And use it in template by

```
{{current_map|safe}}
```

In teality this is a syring content tat easely could be modified by

```
.replace()
```

and you coud add height, or change proportion.

Also you could use

```
f=folium.Figure(height="100%"
current_map.add(f)
```

And in this case

```
current_map._repr_html_()
```

will return

Sou you could manage size of follium window.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this similar problem while back

I solved it by changing the style of the map where i rendered it `position:fixed;`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
context = {'map': map.get_root().render()}
return render(request, template_name="index.html", context=context)
```

index.html:

```
<html> 
    {{map|safe}}
</html>
```